# Stripped Kernel config causes processes to go defunct when killed

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

### The problem is not caused by the kernel config.

I realized that I was previously testing with the wrong kernel. While re-testing, only my changes caused the issue with Ubuntu config as well.

Below is the original question.

---

I am doing some kernel development, and for that, I set up a stripped down kernel config for my Laptop which I am using for testing to speed up compilation.

The problem I am facing with this config is that, killed processes persist in defunct state. Nothing else change except the kernel config. If I compile with the Ubuntu kernel config, this behavior is not observed.

I tried to kill the parent process of the defunct processes, but they either become defunct as well, or the child process become a child of init which then I cannot kill and apparently does not call SIGCHLD on its children.

This is terrible to the point where I have to force-reboot the machine because it gets stuck during reboot waiting for processes to shut down. !

Comment: hi! Welcome here :) sorry, reading 7446 lines of kernel config won't work for us. Can you tell us what you actually changed, or at least offer a diff to the reference kernel config?

Comment: Sorry, what I did to create this config was following the steps in ./scripts/kconfig/streamline_config.pl

Comment: honestly, the last time that script was really updated content-wise, aside from one additional "keep this" mechansim, was 2013… I don't think there's strong guarantees it still works with distro kernels. My guess is: you'd have an easier (and still fast) way of working with `ccache`, which should [work again for the kernel](https://github.com/ccache/ccache/issues/792).

Comment: Some diff of the bootlog would also be welcome.

Comment: While I was trying to create the boot diff, I realized I might have been testing previously with a wrong kernel... I rebuilt vanilla 5.19 kernel with the stripped down config and did not produce the issue. I rebuilt my changes on top with the Ubuntu config, and the issue appeared. I think I might have introduced a memory leak that prevents processes from correctly releasing their resources.